# Click event for edittext drawable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am using this thing -

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchFor"
            android:layout_width="240dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:hint="Search Here"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/forward"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Now as I have set the an image to this edittext how can I fire a click event on that image note it is an Edittext means I will type in my query I have tried click for edittext but then it gets fired even when I type in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do this. You have to implement your `onTouchListener` for the `EditText` and if the Action event is `ACTION_UP` check if the x coords of the touch intersect the x coords of your drawable